# Why is there no instance of the constructor?

Tags: c++, pointers, wxwidgets

I am new to wxWidgets, and am trying to pass in a pointer to my parent window using the `this` keyword.

Here is the code.

The code for the frames header file

myframe.h

```
#pragma once
#include <wx/wx.h>

class MyFrame:public wxFrame
{
public :
    MyFrame(const wxString& title);
    ~MyFrame();

public:
    wxGauge* gh = nullptr;
};
```

The code for the definition of the frame class

myframe.cpp

```
#include "MyFrame.h"
#include <wx/wx.h>

MyFrame::MyFrame(const wxString& title) :wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, title, wxPoint(30, 30), wxSize(600, 600))
{
    wxButton* bt = new wxButton(this);  
}
```

app.h

```
#pragma once
#include <wx/wx.h>

class App :public wxApp
{
    bool OnInit();
};
```

app.cpp

```
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include "App.h"
#include "MyFrame.h"

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(App);

bool App::OnInit()
{
    MyFrame* frame = new MyFrame("GUi");
    frame->Show();
    frame->Center();
    
    return true;
}
```

Before I run the code, VS give me an error on this line:

```
wxButton* bt = new wxButton(this);
```

where there is a red wave under the opening parenthesis.

If I ignore it and run the code, I get this error:

```
1>D:\Projects\visualStudio\cppStuff\wxWidget\learnWxWidget\learnWxWidget\MyFrame.cpp(9,29): error C2665: 'wxButton::wxButton': no overloaded function could convert all the argument types
1>C:\WxWidgets\include\wx\msw\button.h(82,5): message : could be 'wxButton::wxButton(const wxButton &)'
1>D:\Projects\visualStudio\cppStuff\wxWidget\learnWxWidget\learnWxWidget\MyFrame.cpp(9,29): message : 'wxButton::wxButton(const wxButton &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'MyFrame *' to 'const wxButton &'
1>D:\Projects\visualStudio\cppStuff\wxWidget\learnWxWidget\learnWxWidget\MyFrame.cpp(9,30): message : Reason: cannot convert from 'MyFrame *' to 'const wxButton'
1>D:\Projects\visualStudio\cppStuff\wxWidget\learnWxWidget\learnWxWidget\MyFrame.cpp(9,29): message : while trying to match the argument list '(MyFrame *)'
1>Done building project "learnWxWidget.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

Comment: Nowhere here: https://docs.wxwidgets.org/latest/classwx_button.html#pub-methods, you will see a constructor with just one parameter....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [wxWidgets documentation](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/latest/classwx_button.html#pub-methods), `wxButton` does not have a constructor that accepts only a parent window as a parameter. At the very least, you need to also provide an `id` for your button, just like you are doing with your `wxFrame`, eg:

```
wxButton* bt = new wxButton(this, desiredIdHere);
```